# What are some examples of infinite nonabelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, big-list, infinite-groups

I can only think of the general linear groups GLn(R). What are some other examples, if any?

Comment: There are many subgroups of $GL_n(\Bbb R)$.  Of course, there's also $GL_n(\Bbb C)$.

Comment: Is there any particular motivation for listing examples of groups like these?

Comment: You might wanna look into free groups

Comment: How about $S_3 \times \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Not particularly, just curious! A prof. once asked for an example on an exam, and I could only think of this one. Was wondering if there were others.

Comment: In the same vein as Alka, you might want to look at the fundamental group of a bouquet of circles.

Comment: Tarski monsters just to mess with your intuition.

Comment: To amplify the comment from @Rohan, take the direct product of any nonabelian group with any infinite group.

Comment: Free group on two generators. (Or any number of generators, really, as long as it's more than one.)

Comment: Try to accept  some answer if it solves ur question

Answer (score 9):

The bijections of an infinite set $X$.

Answer (score 5):

1. Take the group product $A\times B$ where $A$ is any non-Abelian group and $B$ is any infinite group.
2. On the set $\mathbb R^2$ let $(x,y)+^* (x',y')=(x+x', y+y'e^x).$ Then $(\mathbb R^2,+^*)$ is a non-Abelian group.

   It is also an orderable group: Let $(x,y)<^*(x',y')$ iff  $[\;(x<x')$ or $(x=x'\land y<y')\;].$ Then $<^*$ is a linear order, and for all $p,q,r \in \mathbb R^2$ we have $p<^*q\implies ((p+^*r<^*q+^*r)\land (r+^*p<^*r+^*q)).$
3. For $2\leq n\in \mathbb N$ take the set of  $n\times n$ matrices of real numbers (or of complex numbers) that are invertible in matrix multiplication.

Comment: Your third example is the one they already knew.

Comment: @Mark. I was unfamiliar with the notation  GLn(R).

Comment: GLn(R) is general linear group which id defined excatly damr as you mentioned above in 3 examples

Answer (score 4):

Jorge mentioned the group of all permutations of an infinite set. This is an example of an automorphism group of a structure - namely, the structure which is just an infinite set, with no relations, operations, etc.

In general, automorphism groups are neither abelian nor finite. For example, the automorphism group of the field $\mathbb{C}$ has size continuum, and is very non-abelian. (By contrast, note that the field $\mathbb{R}$ has *no* nontrivial automorphisms!)

Similarly, structures built by "amalgamating" lots of small pieces in a sufficiently "generic" way (Fraisse limits and the Urysohn space come to mind) have lots of automorphisms, and their automorphism groups are generally non-abelian.